# Jmeter - using url encode and groovy functions together

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I have a groovy function

```
${__groovy(import groovy.time.TimeCategory; def now = new Date(); use(TimeCategory) { def nowPlusOneYear = now + 12.month - 1.day; return nowPlusOneYear.format('dd/MM/YYYY')},)}
```

This function returns a value. The value needs to be encoded. Tried using

```
${__urlencode(${__groovy(import groovy.time.TimeCategory; def now = new Date(); use(TimeCategory) { def nowPlusOneYear = now + 12.month - 1.day; return nowPlusOneYear.format('dd/MM/YYYY')},)}
```

But this is not the right way. Could someone help me with an appropriate solution.

Regards,
Ajith

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest option is just performing the [URL encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) directly in Groovy via [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) class:

```
${__groovy(import groovy.time.TimeCategory; def now = new Date(); use(TimeCategory) { def nowPlusOneYear = now + 12.month - 1.day; return URLEncoder.encode(nowPlusOneYear.format('dd/MM/YYYY')\, 'UTF-8')},)}
```

Alternatively you can store the result into a JMeter Variable

```
${__groovy(import groovy.time.TimeCategory; def now = new Date(); use(TimeCategory) { def nowPlusOneYear = now + 12.month - 1.day; return nowPlusOneYear.format('dd/MM/YYYY')},myDate)}
```

[image]

and then call the [urlencode() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) on that variable:

```
${__urlencode(${myDate})}
```

[image]

More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)